# How to get value of a foreign key for a table insert

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm currently creating an application which is based on football. Initially a login is required for the user to use the application which is stored on a database. After this the user is presented to the main menu where a section can be chosen to rate a ground. From here the ratings can be saved and stored into the database as well. The database i currently have contains 2 tables one has userid as the primary key:

```
tbl_client  CREATE TABLE `tbl_client` (
 `userid` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The rating table has id as the primary key and userid as its foreign key.

```
tbl_rating  CREATE TABLE `tbl_rating` (
 `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `userid` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `arsenal` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `chelsea` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `liverpool` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `manchesterC` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 `manchesterU` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `userid` (`userid`),
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_rating_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `tbl_client` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

For my rating php file i have:

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include_once 'init.php';
 
$arsenal = $_POST["arsenal"];
$chelsea = $_POST["chelsea"];
$liverpool = $_POST["liverpool"];
$manchesterC = $_POST["manchesterC"];
$manchesterU= $_POST["manchesterU"];
 
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_rating` (`id`,`userid`,`arsenal`, `chelsea`, `liverpool`,`manchesterC`, `manchesterU`) VALUES (NULL, NULL,'".$arsenal."', '".$chelsea."', '".$liverpool."', '".$manchesterC."', '".$manchesterU."');";
if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    echo '{"message":"Unable to save the data to the database."}';
    die(mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
```

This allows me to insert the data into the database fine if the userid isn't included.
Therefore I was wondering how would i get the logged on userid to have a valid relation with the rated grounds. Off the top of my head I think I need to select the userid from the client table in order to have a value inserted for the userid field on the rating table.However i'm not to sure so a 2nd opinion would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Login php

```html
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'connection.php';
 
 class User {
  
  private $db;
  private $connection;
  
  function __construct() {
   $this -> db = new DB_Connection();
   $this -> connection = $this->db->getConnection();
  }
  
  public function does_user_exist($email,$password)
  {
   $query = "Select * from tbl_client where email='$email' and password = '$password' ";
   $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    $json['success'] = ' Welcome '.$email;
    echo json_encode($json);
    mysqli_close($this -> connection);
    $_SESSION["userid"] = $loggedInUserId;
   }else{
    
    $json['error'] = ' wrong login details';
   
    echo json_encode($json);
    mysqli_close($this->connection);
   }
   
  }
  
 }
 $user = new User();
 if(isset($_POST['email'],$_POST['password'])) {
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = md5($_POST['password']);
  
  if(!empty($email) && !empty($password)){
   
   
   $user-> does_user_exist($email,$password);
   $_SESSION["userid"] = $loggedInUserId;
   
  }else{
   echo json_encode("you must type both inputs");
  }
  
 }
 
 
?>
```

rating php

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include_once 'init.php';
session_start();
$userId = $_SESSION["userid"];

$arsenal = $_POST["arsenal"];
$chelsea = $_POST["chelsea"];
$liverpool = $_POST["liverpool"];
$manchesterC = $_POST["manchesterC"];
$manchesterU= $_POST["manchesterU"];
 


 
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_rating` (`id`,`userid`,`arsenal`, `chelsea`, `liverpool`,`manchesterC`, `manchesterU`) VALUES (NULL,'".$userId."','".$arsenal."', '".$chelsea."', '".$liverpool."', '".$manchesterC."', '".$manchesterU."');";
if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    echo '{"message":"Unable to save the data to the database."}';
 die(mysqli_error($con));
}
 
?>
```

Comment: After the user logs in, you could create a session variable $_SESSION['userID'] = $userID

Then, when inserting the rating you could just get the logged on user ID.

Comment: Thank you I like this method, I can understand what is happening and why.unfortunately its not working so I must have an error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into [PHP sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp). That way you could store the logged-in user's id in the session and just reference it whenever you needed. So, your code would become:

Where-ever you do your login:

```
<?php
session_start();
//... your login code
//... after valid login
$_SESSION["userId"] = $loggedInUserId;
?>
```

Your other code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include_once 'init.php';
session_start();

$userId = $_SESSION["userId"]
$arsenal = $_POST["arsenal"];
$chelsea = $_POST["chelsea"];
$liverpool = $_POST["liverpool"];
$manchesterC = $_POST["manchesterC"];
$manchesterU= $_POST["manchesterU"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_rating` (`id`,`userid`,`arsenal`, `chelsea`, `liverpool`,`manchesterC`, `manchesterU`) VALUES (NULL,'".$userId."','".$arsenal."', '".$chelsea."', '".$liverpool."', '".$manchesterC."', '".$manchesterU."');";
```

Also on a side-note, since your `userid` column is auto-increment, no reason to make it `NOT NULL`. Just give it `NULL`. That way you don't need to specify it in your insert queries.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've tried it but error "Unable to save the data to the database" Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key fails ('db_client'.'tbl_rating', CONSTRAINT 'tbl_rating_ibfk_1' Foreign key ('userid')

Comment: appears could there be an error with my updated login php? I will edit my post to add the updated php files.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include_once 'init.php';
 
$arsenal = $_POST["arsenal"];
$chelsea = $_POST["chelsea"];
$liverpool = $_POST["liverpool"];
$manchesterC = $_POST["manchesterC"];
$manchesterU= $_POST["manchesterU"];
 
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_rating` (`id`,`userid`,`arsenal`, `chelsea`, `liverpool`,`manchesterC`, `manchesterU`) VALUES (NULL, NULL,'".$arsenal."', '".$chelsea."', '".$liverpool."', '".$manchesterC."', '".$manchesterU."');";
if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    echo '{"message":"Unable to save the data to the database."}';
    die(mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
```

Comment: Posting code - only answers is not good. Please post some explanation of your code.

Comment: This wouldn't correct my problem unfortunately as NULL will just become the value within my userid.